# Unicode binded Special Auxiliaries character output error in report

Tags: mysql, unicode, crystal-reports

I inserted a string into a mysql utf-8 database as `අධ්‍යාපන`. But the output in the Report displays as : `අධ් ්‍ය පන`.

This happens to other binding characters too. What solution can I use to fix this?

Comment: Did you check ur database and the string is the same? If it's the same, sometimes crystal report don't manage very well some kinds of fonts. Try to change the font.

Comment: yes. It seems to be crystal report can't manage the fonts that I use. I have tried with several fonts that use commonly in the software recommended by other developers. But none did work with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have an "answer", but further info.  Maybe you or someone else can take it from here.  I know nothing about Sinhala.)

Hex for the first should be

```
E0B685 E0B6B0 E0B78A E2808D E0B6BA E0B78F E0B6B4 E0B6B1
```

is that what a `SELECT HEX(...)` shows?  The other is

```
E0B685 E0B6B0 E0B78A 20 E0B78A E2808D E0B6BA 20 E0B6B4 E0B6B1
```

Notice the spaces (`20`) in it.  I wonder what added the spaces.

Can you explain these two characters?  One was duplicated, the other was removed??

```
UTF=8      Unicode          Meaning
E0B78A     3530=x0DCA  [්]  NSM  SINHALA SIGN AL-LAKUNA
E0B78F     3535=x0DCF  [ා]    L  SINHALA VOWEL SIGN AELA-PILLA
```

Comment: The spaces were added by me. And these two characters are Special Auxiliaries in Sinhala language.The mysql output of these character binding comes as this first letter 1)   ්‍ය <letter>Y    but the expected output should be like this 2) ධ්‍ය‍  <letter>\y ..

Comment: Could it be that adding the spaces changes how the "signs" work?

Comment: No. the output from the database comes without the spaces. here I used spaces to simplify the results to show here.

Comment: Then I am totally lost -- I see the non-space characters moving around.