# Exception occurs when displaying Sinhala Unicode strings

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode, crystal-reports

When I use Sinhala Unicode strings such as `අධ්‍යාපනය` or `ශ්‍රීලංකා` I get this exception:

> Exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

How can I resolve this? I use Crystal Reports 13 with Visual Studio 2015, and a mySQL server as the database.

Comment: Specify a little more. Where did you got the exception?

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752865/unicode-binded-special-auxiliaries-character-output-error-in-report

Comment: I'm building a print Clint  to query and print data from a database. I have to take Sinhala characters in the database (mysql) and view on the crystal report. I uses **utf 8** for **character set** in the database and **utf8_general_c**i for collection